# If Error Then Blank

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for taking a look at my question. Know that I am new to stackoverflow and VBA I have a long macro I've been working on. At one point in the macro I have to convert "Start Depth" (L) and "End Depth" (M) from "m" to "ft". Then I subtract the two to find the "Footage" (N). However, some of the values in the columns are originally left blank. So, after making my conversions and subtractions, I'm left with "#VALUE!" which is giving me errors later on in the macro. Originally I had changed all of the blanks to 0's before the conversions and subtractions. But, After "finishing" the macro I realize the zeros are messing with presenting the data. So, I'd like to just do the conversions and subtractions and then, change all the "#VALUES!" back to blanks. I found some stuff on this but nothing that I could (that i know of) use or specific to me:
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=60740     and    https://superuser.com/questions/715744/excel-2010-formula-how-do-i-write-this-formula-vba

Here is what i was using to change blanks into 0's

```
Worksheet1.Select
lastrow = Range("A666666").End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("A1:Q" & lastrow)
    If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
        cell.Value = 0
    End If
Next
```

Here is the code resulting in errors. Note: The data starts with blanks and after using these formulas I am given errors because some of the original cells begin as null or blanks. Also, These lines aren't in this order but, they are the lines leaving errors.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONVERT(RC[2],""m"",""ft"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:O2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:O" & lastrow)
Range("N1") = "Footage"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & lastrow)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: It would probably be most helpful if you showed the portion of the code that yields the `#VALUE!` error results. Easiest to address it at that point, and not somewhere further in the macro/procedure.

Comment: NB: You can edit your quesition to include the additional code, do **not** try to put it in the comments as some people do :)

Comment: Well that is what I tried to do originally but, by the time I reached the end of my macro and attempted using it, I realized that adding more zero's was skewing my data. So, I need to keep the blanks in the data.

Comment: useful question, but I've down-voted it because of too many unnecessary words. basically all I needed is to read the title (my problem that I was interested in) and to read @AndASM 's answer, wich is much better that the question itself, btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends if the `#VALUE!` is being generated from a formula or from VBA code.

### Formula

If it's being generated from a formula, wrap the formula in the IFERROR function. This was added in Excel 2007 I believe. So for example if your formula was:

```
=A1-B1
```

Then you could put

```
=IFERROR(A1-B1,"")
```

Which is saying, if A1-B1 is an error, return "", otherwise return the result of A1-B1.

### VBA

If the value is being generated by VBA you could write a helper function that works like IFERROR

```
Public Function MyIfError(value As Variant, value_if_error As Variant)
 If IsError(value) Then
    MyIfError = value_if_error
 Else
   MyIfError = value
 End If
End Function
```

And then pass your value through that.

Comment: Or you could do `val = IIF(IsError(val),value_if_error,val)`

Comment: Hi AndASM!  Thanks for helping. The errors are coming from formulas   written in the macro. I tried using IfError for the first time and I am given a "Sub or Function not defined" compiling error. exmp
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = IfError("=CONVERT(RC[2],""m"",""ft"")", "")

Comment: @Ryan `"=iferror(convert(` it's a formula function not a VBA function. Your statement makes no sense either way though. Setting FormulaR1C1 to the results of a string passed to some function? FormulaR1C1 takes a string. How is the function going to change the string that you couldn't just write in the first place?

Comment: @AndASM Sorry I am still new to the way vba works and its functions. Half of my code is from recording and half from my writing (It's how I'm teaching myself). I'm not sure what you were trying to say because there are no strings involved in my data. So, I assume that FormulaR1C1 turns int's to strings. I don't know. Your statement confused me. BUT!!! I got it working with the IfError. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Ryan `Cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Cat"` is putting the formula `=Cat` into the cell referenced to by `Cell`. It's kind of like you writing `=Cat` into a cell. Excel then recalculates that cell and it's value is updated. `Cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Cat"` is not putting the value itself in or calculating the value directly. Hopefully that makes sense and helps.

Comment: @DavidZemens I don't think this would work as IIRC both value_if_error and val will be evaluated whatever the result of the test

Comment: @wotter you don't *think* it will work, but did you try it? Assuming the left-side of the assignment statement can accept a variant (which would handle an Error type), `val = IIF(IsError(val), value_if_error, val)` will absolutely work.

Comment: @wotter IIF would fail if you attempted to *evaluate an expression* within the function call, e.g., `IIF(IsError(val), value_if_error, (1/0))` but since `val` has already been evaluated, it will work, provided the caveat mentioned in preceding comment.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but it does fix the presentation of Zero's on your worksheet. You can use the following setting to show Zeros as Blanks through VBA: `ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False` It might be a consideration instead of looping through everything looking for 0's and switching them to blanks manually.

Comment: Thanks JNevil but unfortunately, I need the zero's that are original in the data to stay.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheet1.Select
lastrow = Range("A666666").End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("A1:Q" & lastrow)
    If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
        cell.Value = 0
    End If
Next

For Each cell In Range("A1:Q" & lastrow)
    cell.value = WorksheetFunction.Iferror(cell.value,"")
    End If
Next
```

I'm sorry I don't have opprtunity to test it right but give it a try.
Bottom line is that I simply included a second loop that runs `IFERROR` function on your data.

Comment: HI sgp667, this seems like it would solve my problem in the most simplest way. But, for some reason it literally does nothing! I can't figure out why. All I need is the second FOR loop. So, I commented out my original loop, used yours, put a stop before and after it and, nothing happened! I don't get why.