# Error within If Not IsError function without returning Else

Tags: excel, vba

Post has been **Updated** below original post

I am working with two tables and want to have them connected however, the first section contains more values than the second one. I was able to work that out by adding an `IfError` within the `Evaluate` function, seen from code example (1) to (2), (using help from [If Error Then Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066575/if-error-then-blank))

(1)

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Cell1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=INDEX(data,MATCH(value,lookup_column,FALSE),column)")
```

(2)

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Cell1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=INDEX(data,MATCH(value,lookup_column,FALSE),column), Cell2")
```

However, I still would like a message saying that there was an error so I tried

```
Sub Name()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo Msg

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Cell1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=INDEX(data,MATCH(value,lookup_column,FALSE),column), Cell2")

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Cell1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=INDEX(data,MATCH(value,lookup_column,FALSE),column)")

    Exit Sub
Msg:         MsgBox "You've had a fatal error"
    End

End Sub
```

It did not return a message, I am assuming this is because the code for VBA was written correctly and it was the Excel function code that had an error. So is there a way to use another function to determine the excel error?

This is a sub part of a larger coding so I know it is something that can be done in excel stand alone, but this is just a minor part of the whole. Thanks in advance.

**UDATE**:

With comments I was able remove the Evaluate function and replace the original code with the following:

```
Sub SetWaterfall ()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


 Dim vMatchVal As Variant

If Not IsError(vMatchVal) Then

vMatchVal = Application.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SelectLine"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AS8:AS34"), 0)


Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AW45").Value = Application.Index(Sheets("Controls").Range("AR8:AR34"), vMatchVal)

Else
Worksheets("Controls").Range("AW45").Value = "Not Data"

MsgBox "First number not found"
End If


End Sub
```

The issue is still that the index/match functions returns a `#NA` error and the message box never appears.

(Help converting Index/Match function from Excel formula to VBA code https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/691904-translate-index-match-function-vba-code.html)

(If this edit process is not the correct procedure for let me know and I'll close the post)

Comment: It's best to avoid use of `Evaluate` altogether.

Comment: Can you even do Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate ? And you need to build a concatenated string if those are variables inside. Otherwise, is this pseudo code that does not compile?

Comment: What's `Cell1`?  And the rogue `End`?  Also, `Name` is the name of an [existing command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/name-statement) so I'd suggest picking a different name for your procedure.

Comment: @ashleedawg Is there another way to do an Index(match ()) without evaluate?   Cell1 Is where the end result value will be placed? The Name is not that I was just trying to make it generic for the purpose of this outpost.  The rouge end was just something I was following from another message board on this subject.

Comment: @QHarr it works and I even did a test in just normal excel and it work exactly as it should have. My knowledge is limited on how the code should or should not work I just know it did.

Comment: @QHarr - there are two forms of Evaluate: Application.Evaluate (the default) will evaluate the expression as a formula in the context of whatever is the active sheet.  `Worksheet.Evaluate` uses the specified worksheet as the evaluation context.

Comment: @TimWilliams Many thanks!

Comment: `If Not IsError(vMatchVal) Then` occurs **before** your assignment to `vMatchVal` variable :)

Comment: @DavidZemens You are the best ! I knew it was a small thing. Thank you @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your revised code, you have the `If Not IsError` test *preceding* the assignment to the variable you're testing for error!

Let's fix that, and try some other refactoring (for legibility's sake). If this is still not working as expected, you're going to need to provide some example data which others can use to replicate the error.

```
Sub SetWaterfall()

' It's not necessary to disable ScreenUpdating for this procedure...
' Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim theSheet as Worksheet, controls as Worksheet
Dim vMatchVal As Variant
Dim lookupVal as String
Dim matchRange as Range, indexRange as Range

Set theSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set controls = Sheets("Controls")
Set matchRange = theSheet.Range("AS8:AS34")
Set indexRange = controls.Range("AR8:AR34")

lookupValue = theSheet.Range("SelectLine").Value
vMatchVal = Application.Match(lookupVal, matchRange, 0)

If Not IsError(vMatchVal) Then
    theSheet.Range("AW45").Value = Application.Index(indexRange, vMatchVal)
Else
    controls.Range("AW45").Value = "Not Data"
    MsgBox "First number not found"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I can't edit the post but the Index range is AR8:AR34 not AS8:AS34, just so if anyone else reads this they know